# How to create an Elasticsearch mapping with not_analyzed nested fields?

Tags: elasticsearch

How do I create a mapping with nested fields, where the nested fields are not_analyzed?

I can't figure out the correct mapping, see my example below.

Data which is indexed into the fields taxonomyHMG.0, taxonomyHMG.1, taxonomyHMG.2, etc. is processed through the standard tokenizer (can be tested by running a facet query).

This happens although all the nested fields are set to "not_analyzed". I am running ES 1.4.5. What am I missing?

```
        "taxonomyHMG": {
                "properties": {
                "level0": {
                    "type": "string","index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "level1": {
                    "type": "string","index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "level2": {
                    "type": "string","index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "level3": {
                    "type": "string","index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "level4": {
                    "type": "string","index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "level5": {
                    "type": "string","index": "not_analyzed"
                }
                }
```

**Update 7.20.15**
All resolved. Problems were caused by simple typo :-)

Thx Andrei

Comment: You're testing this against a new index?

Comment: Can you show us a sample document that you're indexing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not checking this correctly, because your mapping looks good, the document being indexed looks good.

How I would check it is like this:

```
GET /hmgshopmonitor/items/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "taxonomyHMG",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "taxonomyHMG.0": {
            "value": "Pullover & Strick"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I added a test query plus the results I get... this is really strange. It seems that as soon a value is nested, the "not_analyzed" directive is ignored.

Comment: Try this query and tell me what you get back: `{
  "facets": {
    "termssss": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "level0",
        "size": 50,
        "order": "count"
      },
      "nested":"taxonomyHMG" 
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}`.

Comment: {
  "error" : "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query_fetch], all shards failed; shardFailures {[CUrkWvbAQyC2aFL3NcCJiQ][hmgzanoxmonitor][0]: SearchParseException[[hmgzanoxmonitor][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{ \"facets\": { \"termssss\": { \"terms\": { \"field\": \"level0\", \"size\": 50, \"order\": \"count\" }, \"nested\":\"taxonomyHMG\" } }, \"size\": 0 }]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[hmgzanoxmonitor][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [facet nested path [taxonomyHMG] is not nested]]; }]",
  "status" : 400
}

Comment: Ok. Try your query (the one from kibana) but with the type, as well: `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/hmgzanoxmonitor/items/_search?pretty` or however the type is called (in your example it was `items`).

Comment: did that. it still returns the lowercased, analyzed terms. I also checked the mapping once more. it is definitely set to not_analyzed. {
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 153,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "facets" : {
    "terms" : {
      "_type" : "terms",
      "missing" : 3,
      "total" : 187,
      "other" : 0,
      "terms" : [ {
        "term" : "damen",
        "count" : 70
      }, etc.

Comment: Ok. Then provide the output of `GET /hmgzanoxmonitor/items/_mapping`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83768/discussion-between-jabb-and-andrei-stefan).